# Migrating to Software Recs

Tags: discussion

Now that the Software Recommendations SE is up and running, would it be better to instantly migrate Software Recs off-topic questions, rather than comment and closevote?

We continue to get quite a few software recommendations questions. To comment, vote for close, then wait for the consensus vote takes time and effort, for little gain to the OP and none for PMSE other than maintaining cleanliness. If we migrated all software recommendations immediately it would save time and effort on PMSE for the same benefits (cleanliness) and additionally the OP would be in a better position to receive an answer.

Comment: Is it possible to re-locate a post?

Comment: Yes. They can be migrated to another SE site.

Answer (score 3):

The Software Recommendations Stack Exchange site is a specialty Stack Exchange site.  The same quality guidelines on other Stack Exchange sites still apply, perhaps to a larger degree on Software Recommendations due to the nature of the topic.

The main reason most software recommendation questions get closed on most SE sites isn't because they're software recommendation questions, but because they don't fit the quality of the site.

From [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information):

> One of the key problems that I see Software Recommendations having, is people asking extremely vague and simple questions that ultimately boil down to one of the two close reasons we see on the rest of the network:
>
> - too broad
> - unclear what you're asking

As a result, most SE communities have chosen to avoid questions seeking software recommendations simply because they lack detail, water down the site, and become both a distraction and a garden for spam.

But Software Recommendations SE created a set of guidelines to help ensure that such questions have substance and value, that there's a clear purpose for the need for the software and so that answers given are backed with facts, references, and experiences and not just because the software is someone's favorite.

Thus, I wouldn't recommend migrating any Software Recommendation questions, unless they are extremely well-written with good spelling and grammar, containing plenty of detail about the needs and requirements, and other points outlined in the Software Recommendation SE site's guidelines. Hope this helps.

Comment: One problem with that is that we, in effect, become the moderating community for Software Recs, applying that site's question guidelines here. I for one am getting rather tired of trotting out the same old "Questions requiring software recommendations (...) try Software Recs", Closevote, Downvote process... Another way to look at this is if the OP actually *did* post their question there then the quality of the post would be moderated in-site in the usual way, but it is off our books (when it shouldn't have been on our books in the first place)...

Comment: That's why it's best to just close them and maybe refer them to the Software Recs site.  For comments folks in the community find they make often, I've found this Stack App to be quite valuable, the [pro forma comments script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).